# Consider functions f:{1,2,3,4,5}→{a,b,c,d,e,f}. How many functions have the property that f(1)≠c or f(2)≠f, or both?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

So I'm working through this problem, and I think my error is that I'm over counting, but I'm not sure.

Question:

> Consider functions f:{1,2,3,4,5}→{a,b,c,d,e,f}. How many functions have the property that f(1)≠a or f(2)≠b, or both?

And I'm trying this.

> 6^5 - C(5,4)1! + C(5,4)1!

Am I thinking about this the right way? Any help to get me started would be great.

Comment: How did you come to the answer you gave there?  Hard to say whether or not your thinking is solid if you haven't shown us your thinking. :-)

Comment: Ok, so I figured that 6^5 was the total amount of functions, but then that would be over counting them, so I needed to subtract C(5,4) as I am choosing from the last 5 letters 4 ways that the domain can go to?

Comment: You are not over-counting the set of all the functions from {1,2,3,4,5} to {a,b,c,d,e,f}. There are $6^5$ different functions from a 5-member set to a 6-member set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer isn't correct.  I'm not sure where you're getting the terms you're subtracting from $6^5.$

There are $6^5$ functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \} \to \{a, b, c, d, e, f \}$.  Of those, you have to subtract the functions where $f(1)=a$ **and** $f(2)=b$.  Any function that doesn't satisfy both of those constraints is fine.  There are $6^3$ "bad" functions, so your answer should be $6^5-6^3 = 35 \cdot 216 =7560.$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The functions $f$ that you **don’t** want are those such that $f(1)=a$ **and** $f(2)=b$; if $B$ is the set of such functions, there are $6^5-|B|$ functions that you **do** want. If $f\in B$, $f(3)$, $f(4)$, and $f(5)$ can be any members of $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$, so what is $|B|$?